# Excel VBA: There must be a better way to use a loop to delete rows based on cell contents

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

A report produces a sheet that looks like this:

[image: Fig1: Starting Data]
Format is inherited from source data, data is in cols A, D and G, with A merging ABC, D merging DEF and G on its own.

I want to keep only the lines highlighted in blue. I want the macro to check the contents of G:G and if Cell.Text = "" then entirerow.delete, else leave it alone.

Only problem is when it deletes row 2, then row 3 becomes row 2, meaning that it doesn't delete it, because it's already checked row 2. What was row 4 now becomes row 3, which is the next one to check, and it sees that text is there and doesn't delete, moves on to row four, deletes it, row 5 becomes row 4, remains unchecked, it moves on to row 6 (now row 5), sees that's blank, deletes it, but row 7 now becomes row 6 and isn't deleted... and so on.

The only way I've found around it is to use GOTO to restart the loop, then to use another GOTO to get out of the loop early. I appreciate that probably isn't the most elegant solution.

```
iRange = Application.Workbooks(2).Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Debug.Print (iRange)

RestartLoop:

For Each rCell In Application.Workbooks(2).Worksheets(2).Range("G2:G" & iRange)

    If Not rCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = "" Then

        If rCell.Text = "" Then
            Debug.Print (rCell.Address)
            rCell.EntireRow.Delete
            GoTo RestartLoop
        End If

    Else0

        GoTo LeaveLoop

    End If
Next rCell

LeaveLoop:
'Do the next thing
```

(code is Option Explicit: Dim iRange As Integer Dim rCell as Range in declarations at top of code)

Here's the debug.print:

```
26 
$G$2
$G$2
$G$3
$G$3
$G$3
$G$3
$G$3
$G$3
$G$3
$G$3
$G$3
$G$4
$G$4
$G$4
$G$4
$G$4
$G$6
$G$6
$G$7
```

If anyone knows of a solution, and can also explain it for a layman, I'd appreciate it. The solution needs to be dynamic, because the original sheet produced is a different length each time, with a different number of blank and blue cells each time.

I have searched around a little but either I'm not understanding the answers fully, or they seem to give me the same problem.

Comment: The simple answer is to use a `For r = iRange To 2 Step -1` loop.  The more complicated answer is to find one of the hundred or more similar questions so that we can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Stay positive @YowE3K, I'll find a good dupe :P

Comment: @CallumDA - Found one.

Comment: The filter may assist on a simple empty cell delete, filter for blanks, delete selected data, filter off.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I put this at the bottom:

`I have searched around a little but either I'm not understanding the answers fully, or they seem to give me the same problem. `

Won't `r=iRange To 2` create an infinite loop unless I continue to use `If value = ""` and `GOTO` to escape the loop? Which, like my code, works, but I'm looking to learn the best practice. 

I didn't know about Step-1, which I can play around with, but what's to stop it going to cell.address G0 or G-1 and causing an error?

Comment: Ah. Ok, so in the example marked it explains that you work from the bottom and count up. Which is a practice I wasn't aware of and hence not being able to search for.

Comment: `For r = iRange To 2 Step -1` says to go through the loop once with `r` having a value of `iRange`, then go through it again with a value of `iRange-1`, then `iRange-2`, then `iRange-3`, etc, and stop when it has gone through the loop with a value of `2`.  So it will never go to a value of `1` (or `0` or `-1`).

Comment: The post I referenced above doesn't even delete any row (in the beginning) but merely keeps track of all the rows you wish to delete. Only at the end of the sub all the rows (which should be deleted) will be removed all at once. This makes it extremely fast and also eliminated the problem of (possibly) reviewing / verifying the same row twice.

Comment: I refuse to post it as an answer, but your code will probably become `With Application.Workbooks(2).Worksheets(2)` `For r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 To 2 Step -1` `If .Cells(r, "D").Value <> "" And .Cells(r, "G").Text = "" Then .Rows(r).Delete` `Next` `End With`, but taking some hints from the link provided by @Ralph would allow you to speed things up a bit as well.

Comment: There are loads of ways of doing this. In addition to the ideas given already, you could sort the data by column G, so all blanks are next to each other, find where blanks start and end, then delete all rows at once. Afterwards sort by column A to get back to the original order. (I think) deleting all the rows at once will be quicker than deleting a row at a time in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the below, it works by building up a range from the cells which match your criteria then deleting all of them in one go. **When testing this always do it on a copy of your original to make sure results are as expected before making it permanent**

```
Dim DeleteRng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

IRange = Application.Workbooks(2).Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Debug.Print IRange

' This is dangerous, select workbook using ThisWorkbook, or setting the workbook to a variable
' Not just using the number, this could change when opening other workbooks as well
' Similar with above when setting IRange
For Each rcell In Application.Workbooks(2).Worksheets(2).Range("G2:G" & IRange)
    If Not rcell.Offset(0, -3).value = vbNullString And rcell.Text = vbNullString Then
        If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRng = rcell
        Else
            Set DeleteRng = Union(DeleteRng, rcell)
        End If
    End If
Next rcell
Debug.Print DeleteRng.Address
DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Why are you answering a question that has been clearly identified as a duplicate and has perfectly good answers elsewhere? I'm not 100% sure but I think higher powers than us delete closed questions like this that add no value since they've already been asked and answered elsewhere

Comment: Quite simple really. When I answered it, it wasn't marked as a duplicate - Look at the time stamps

Comment: @CallumDA Would you rather I deleted it?

Comment: @CallumDA - From memory, I think the duplicate questions are usually left (unless they have been marked as poor quality, etc) because they can act as search targets that will then refer people to the "original" question / answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Autofilter on G column for selecting blank rows and then delete those rows, so can have all those rows where there is text in G. This will delete all rows where column G has a blank cell.**New row needs to be added i.e. dummy row so as it serves as a reference point to further select and delete rows**

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
' Add dummy row
Rows("1:1").Copy
Rows("2:2").Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows("2:2").Paste
CutCopyMode = False

'add filter
With ActiveSheet

.AutoFilterMode = False
.Range("A2:G2").AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=" & ""
End With

'delete blank rows
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What is with all the `Select` statements? Don't use the macro recorder output for an answer. It's sloppy at best

Comment: @tom I'm new to VBA, and the only way I know to call a range for any operation is by `select`, will try to learn further. 
Thanks

Comment: Combine the `Selection` and `Select` rows e.g. `Rows(1:1).Select : Selection.Copy` Becomes `Rows(1:1).Copy` unless you need to do something visually you should very very rarely be using `Select` statements

Comment: Thanks for the input.